# spammy URL in Google Analytics for Wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, themes, carousel

I am using wordpress theme with Carousel Slider. Of late I am getting a lot of visitors from Russia with the page co.lumb which does not exist on my website.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this does not appear to be about programming.  This might be on-topic on Webmasters.SE,

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm that this **not** a WordPress issue. It appears to be a hack of Google Analytics instead.

I have a middleman-generated static site. That means just html, no server-side code at all, nevermind  WordPress. In Google Analytics, I'm also seeing the hits to the page "co.lumb" from Russia.

I found the following discussions on the same topic:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/a-non-existent-page-is-showing-up-on-my-analytics
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/74692/what-are-these-unknown-visits-to-my-private-unlisted-webpage

**UPDATE** The best information I've seen so far is here:
http://egenie.biz/blog/russian-spam-traffic-darodar-com-co-lumb/

Yes, this appears to be an attack on Google Analytics which does not even generate hits on your site. There is nothing for you to do, except perhaps to (a) create a filtered view excluding this data in your GA account, and (b) report it to Google.

Comment: To clarify: it's not a hack, it's just referrer spam. Been around since the 1990s when having a "latest referrers" sidebar was all the rage.